# Git Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: macos, git

I had to reinstall OS X Lion on my Macbook Pro, and upon trying to use git I got an error stating `Segmentation fault: 11`.  No matter what git command I try I get that error. I'm just doing this through the Mac terminal. No fancy programs or anything external.

I uninstalled git and just to make sure it was uninstalled I typed `git init` and it gave me a command not found message.

I reinstalled git and I'm still getting the segmentation fault message. I get the message regardless of what directory I'm in and what command I use.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by uninstalling it again and installing 1.8.1 instead of 1.9.2. I guess OS X Lion doesn't like the latest release.

Comment: +1 for following up on solution.  might be good to stick with what gets dropped with xcode ...

Answer (score 2):

Try setting an email address in your git config if you haven't done so already - traced errors and that's what fixed it for me.

git config --global user.email "email@example.com"

Answer (score 1):

**Working with a `Mac OS X Version 10.7.5 (Lion)`**

Uninstalling `Git latest version (2.2.0)` and reinstalling  `Git version 1.8.4.2` worked for me. Here is the [download link](https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/detail?name=git-1.8.4.2-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg&can=2&q=) for `git 1.8.4.2`

It says `snow-leopard` but actually works for `Lion` here is the page with all [git-osx-installer](https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list)

:o)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was using `(2.12.2)` on Windows 7(x64), I downgraded it to `(2.12.1)` and now everything is working fine.